# SharePoint: Common mistakes

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-api

Recently I figured out one terrible thing I was not supposed to do when doing SharePoint development:

```
using (var spSite = SPContext.Current.Site)
{
    // do something
}
```

After some hair pulling I figured out that the code above was actually disposing my current SharePoint context.

This urges me to question if there are any other such common mistakes that I or any other SharePoint developer should not be making?

Comment: Learning it the hard way is ok, but you can only do that by making common mistakes. So your question makes no sense..

Comment: This question is also almost a rant-in-disguise.

Comment: @Caspar Kleijne: I do not agree. Making a common mistake is okay. But finding out what those mistakes are and to not make them in the first place is even better and more productive. Moreover, if what you are saying is true then what do you think all the supporters of this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380819/common-programming-mistakes-for-net-developers-to-avoid) were thinking?

Comment: In that case, don't go the hard way but read a book like Carter's: http://www.amazon.com/SharePoint-Development-Visual-Studio-Microsoft/dp/0321718313

Comment: Read over the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq):"You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."

Answer (score 2):

1. Not disposing SPSite & SPWeb objects you "new" up in your code.
2. Disposing Context.SPSite & SPWeb objects
3. Disposing SPWeb.ParentWeb objects (this is done for you)

See [Best Practices: Using Disposable Windows SharePoint Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973248%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

1. Not using Output Cache with Publishing sites
2. Not using WSP solutions to deploy custom code changes.

Answer (score 1):

For checking your code against these kind of mistakes (What to dispose and what not to), I would suggest using SPDisposeChecker.

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SPDisposeCheck

Also, you can read article by Roger Lamb (on which this tool is based on) for understanding more about this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rogerla/archive/2008/02/12/sharepoint-2007-and-wss-3-0-dispose-patterns-by-example.aspx

Hope it helps.

DG